# Why are these objects not equal?

Tags: javascript, json, compare

I am trying to write a test in JavaScript using Mocha and Chai. At the end of the test, I want to compare 2 JavaScript objects, these should be equal.

The output I get from the test is the following:

```
{ publication: 
   { publication_id: 'pubFetch1',
     title: 'Publication Fetcher',
     person_id: 'uploader',
     URL: 'http://www.pubfetchertest.com',
     publication_year: '2015',
     upload_date: '2015-05-05 00:00:00',
     page_count: '5',
     type: 'paper',
     rating: '0',
     votes: '0',
     abstract: 'Testing the Publication Fetcher',
     location: 'location' },
  comments: 
     [ { commentID: 'comment1',
         personID: 'uploader',
         firstName: 'First',
         lastName: 'Last',
         text: 'Comment Content',
         time: '2015-05-05 10:24:36',
         reactions: [],
         myComment: true },
       { commentID: 'comment2',
         personID: 'author1',
         firstName: 'First',
         lastName: 'Last',
         text: 'Comment Content',
         time: '2015-05-05 11:01:45',
         reactions: [Object],
         myComment: false } ],
   keywords: [ 'keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3' ],
   uploader: { person_id: 'uploader', first_name: 'First', last_name: 'Last' },
   score: 5,
   authors: 
     [ { person_id: 'author1', first_name: 'First', last_name: 'Last' },
       { person_id: 'author2', first_name: 'First', last_name: 'Last' },
       { person_id: 'author3', first_name: 'First', last_name: 'Last' } ],
   editors: [],
   publishers: [] }
```

While the object I want to compare it with, is the following:

```
{ publication: 
      { publication_id: 'pubFetch1',
        title: 'Publication Fetcher',
        person_id: 'uploader',
        url: 'http://www.pubfetchertest.com',
        publication_year: '2015',
        upload_date: '2015-05-05 00:00:00',
        page_count: '5',
        type: 'paper',
        rating: '0',
        votes: '0',
        abstract: 'Testing the Publication Fetcher',
        location: 'location'},
   comments: 
      [{ commentID: 'comment1',
         personID: 'uploader',
         firstName: 'First',
         lastName: 'Last',
         text: 'Comment Content',
         time: '2015-05-05 10:24:36',               
         reactions: [],
         myComment: true},
       { commentID: 'comment2',
         personID: 'author1',
         firstName: 'First',
         lastName: 'Last',
         text: 'Comment Content',
         time: '2015-05-05 11:01:45',
         reactions: [{ commentID: 'comment3',
                       personID: 'author2',
                       firstName: 'First',
                       lastName: 'Last',
                       text: 'Comment Content',
                       time: '2015-05-05 11:02:10',
                       reactions: [],
                       replyID: 'comment2',
                       myComment: false}],
         myComment: false}],
    keywords: ['keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3'],
    uploader: {person_id: 'uploader',
               first_name: 'First',
               last_name: 'Last'},
    score: 5,
    authors: [{person_id: 'author1',
               first_name: 'First',
               last_name: 'Last'},
              {person_id: 'author2',
               first_name: 'First',
               last_name: 'Last'},
              {person_id: 'author3',
               first_name: 'First',
               last_name: 'Last'}],
    editors: [],
    publishers: []
};
```

I don't see any difference in these 2 objects, so why does JavaScript say these are different? I am using `JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2)` to compare these 2 objects.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9akeh8bh/4/

Comment: Could you please provide jsfiddle/plunker?

Comment: Without looking at the objects: In JavaScript, object properties are not in any particular order. So it might be possible that the JSON representation of an object looks different from the JSON representation of another object with the same content.

Comment: you can really find out the differences if you use the tool to help you. Some keys are not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are differences between the two objects; some keys have underscores and some are uppercase.

Have you tried standardising the key names and seeing if the comparison works?

Comment: I have adjusted the keys, but it still returns false. Does it have something to do with the `reactions: [Object]`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `reactions` are different, some contain Objects, some do not.

Comment: My test returns `reactions: [Object]` in once of the `comments`. Should this be compared with `reactions: [Object]` or with the true object?

Comment: how are you getting that test, just `return obj` ?

Comment: there is more than just 'reactions' that are different

Comment: @jonnyknowsbest I know, I have adjusted the keys. A function gets data from a database and builds the object. This build object is compared with a stored object.